# Magento 2 - Checkout. Remove “New Address” Button from checkout billing/shipping address with module for B2B customers

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address, magento2-b2b

[image]

Magento 2 - Checkout. Remove “New Address” Button from checkout billing/shipping address with module for B2B customers

Answer (score 0):

Try these all steps

Step 1: Create the module structure
In the **app/code** directory of your Magento installation.

```
  - app
  - code
    - Vendor
      - Module
        - etc
          - module.xml
        - registration.php
```

Step 2: Create the module declaration file
Create the **module.xml** file in the etc

```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

Step 3: Create the registration file
Create the **registration.php**

```
  <?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 4: Override the checkout layout file
Create the following file in your module's directory: **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-addresses">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout.steps.billing-step.billingAddress.customer-addresses" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.customer-addresses" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 5: Enable the module

> ```
>   php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
>
>   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
>   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
>   php bin/magento cache:clean
> ```

Comment: I want to hide this button for B2B and show this button for B2C how I can handle this any suggestions, please

Comment: this code is not worked

Comment: How you have identified that  a customer is B2C or B2B customer?

Answer (score 0):

Please copy the file from vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

to

app/design/frontend/<theme_dir>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

Remove the below code from the file

```
<!-- Address form pop up -->
        <if args="!isFormInline">
            <div class="new-address-popup">
                <button type="button"
                        class="action action-show-popup"
                        click="showFormPopUp"
                        visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
                    <span translate="'New Address'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
                 visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
                 render="shippingFormTemplate"></div>
        </if>
```